# Changing wordpress url-link in fully grown site

Tags: wordpress

How can i change url of my website which is already heavily coded built in wordpress.

For example :-- 
http://example.com

I want is

http://username.example.com

Do any body have an idea how to do this so that i do not have to change other codes.

Comment: Is the URL always going to be `username.example.com`? Or is the `username` part going to actually change depending on who's logged in? Because this kind of functionality is not natively built into Wordpress, you might be better off using a plugin that changes the htaccess file.

Comment: you might need to change full database url for this and update the htaccess for this.

Comment: @lee  is user login with different name say i am admin so my url will be 
admin.example.com 
if i am jack then my url will be jack.example.com

Comment: can u suggest any plugin ?

Comment: You will find quite a few that should do something like that, you're essentially looking for membership plugins. Although I don't want to sound harsh, but this question is a bit too-broad for the purposes of this site, as it's opinion based.

Comment: can u suggest some plugin free or paid so that i know at least this can happen easily